# Residuals of symmetric Procrustes analyses are not symmetric

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, ecology, procrustes-analysis, vegan

I am trying to replicate the analysis I saw in a paper. One of the step is to describe the relationships between two data tables. I use the `procrustes()` function from the `vegan` package with the argument `,symmetric=` set to `TRUE`.

I have two issues:

1) Although the statistic is the same, the residuals from:

```
procrustes(A, B, symmetric=TRUE)
procrustes(B, A, symmetric=TRUE)
```

are different. This is a problem for me as I would like to have only one vector of residuals for a pair of data tables. Which leads to my second question.

2) What kind of symmetric analysis, or Procrustes variation, could enable me to get the same residuals independently of the order of my two data tables?

I am afraid to continue exploring the residual relationship (not explained by each other) between A and B with two different vectors of residuals.

Here is a an example dataset:

```
jjj<-structure(c(-0.415231390946823, -0.103881950071297, 0.440845385809548, 
            -0.0919098022835367, 0.0681670797616329, -0.109376596649534, 
            -0.180216246093277, 0.0320355486180668, -0.0809718214198884, 
            -0.0516475144057354, 0.0214277268828092, 0.330728182266247, -0.453623227986869, 
            0.106692061747753, -0.218002699941275, -0.112408232838748, -0.114081756762183, 
            -0.306266798006028, -0.190737752990302, -0.458010832699257, -0.109016409199319, 
            -0.168647777435186, -0.140767111916142, 0.327538156481763, 0.101362327621603, 
            0.0962697332763751, -0.0478505749152524, 0.0531010416947144, 
            -0.52362438260925, 0.250030610940299, 0.25714037831202, 0.0148145398303188, 
            0.0425064757600747, -0.0581337915751233, -0.25963167516831, 0.0967640457622825, 
            0.552931779659787, 0.37089482586282, 0.082709234542227, -0.0509757269657317, 
            0.196116163208646, -0.00617811495800244, 0.170695267120604, -0.240419182678008, 
            -0.211037038896914), .Dim = c(15L, 3L))

lll<-structure(c(0.49536693242795, 0.466582663397923, -0.145119433551786, 
                 0.151637067406486, -0.0382685791275805, -0.167907390261346, 0.517714894149158, 
                 -0.0702060982427222, -0.0570940403305044, -0.157799475921808, 
                 0.0572978779058811, -0.199994337647658, 0.167234252697672, 0.219247651046291, 
                 0.354445237114728, 0.133217357588808, -0.0538736533789164, -0.0121256835349961, 
                 0.0981231645289245, 0.0836696143624801, -0.474566818769805, 0.0761659701578307, 
                 -0.254340886219059, -0.164377298914141, -0.224502540629877, 0.294326324529298, 
                 0.0714313979828113, 0.179133324172731, 0.00791931098125838, -0.317994717532408, 
                 -0.156918464493741, 0.0380602919291126, 0.266838534723089, 0.276845743073558, 
                 0.130039057439986, -0.100769319535894, -0.265454289625092, -0.160713284401203, 
                 0.0400166811815559, 0.203321016756949, -0.160953027477904, -0.0245719389193783, 
                 0.0831625412257537, 0.118591016806505, 0.0268775853901903), .Dim = c(15L, 3L))
```

You can see here that the residuals are different:

```
    residuals(procrustes(jjj, lll, symmetric=TRUE))

    site1     site2     site3     site4     site5     site6     site7     site8     site9 
0.1963394 0.2408448 0.1568857 0.1574536 0.1080745 0.4005659 0.2499062 0.2456437 0.1414271 
   site10    site11    site12    site13    site14    site15 
0.2270507 0.2859563 0.1329476 0.2468849 0.1645302 0.1516206 

    residuals(procrustes(lll, jjj, symmetric=TRUE))

     site1      site2      site3      site4      site5      site6      site7      site8 
0.11621180 0.10311944 0.26165198 0.03076077 0.27298092 0.23605756 0.21506970 0.22596903 
     site9     site10     site11     site12     site13     site14     site15 
0.24395170 0.12297483 0.21167006 0.15647634 0.32112479 0.33889141 0.19974906
```

Comment: you may be misunderstanding what this function does "procrustes rotates a configuration to maximum similarity with another configuration" and more at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vegan.pdf ; basic matrix multiplication may also be useful